# I used to take naked pics than my brother saw it and told the whole family about it can I put my trust in Allah and cut my self of from everyone

Tags: family

I Used to take naked pics of my self than my brother saw it and told the whole family about it can I only really on Allah and cut communication from my family

Comment: Mankind will be resurrected naked. Delete photos move on

Answer (score 1):

"Relying on Allah" does not mean you should do whatever you are inclined to and hoping for the best.

It means to try your hardest at obeying the commands of Allah, and being at peace with knowing that He will arrange the best outcome for you if you do so.

"**Follow** what is revealed to you from your Lord. Surely Allah is All-Aware of what you [all] do. **And put your trust in Allah**, for Allah is sufficient as a Trustee of Affairs." [Qur'an, 33:2-3]

Whatever the correct path forward for you is, it most likely does not involve cutting yourself off from your family. Maintaining connection with your blood relatives, especially your parents, is a command from Allah, and cutting away from them is definitely a disobedience to Allah.

"For your Lord has decreed that you worship none but Him. And **honour your parents**. If one or both of them reach old age in your care, never say to them [even] ‘ugh,’ nor yell at them. Rather, address them respectfully..." [Qur'an, 17:23]

Comment: Shukran so much for all the advice